# Are questions about particular investments on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, off-topic

Are questions about particular investments, as in particular stocks or bonds, on topic? For example, could I ask the following question:

Does TGNA's position in broadcasting and low PE make it a compelling value play?

Or What are the chances of MEI Pharma's drugs resulting in profitability? Are they undervalued given historical success rates with drugs at a similar stage?

I think questions about investment vehicles(bonds vs stocks, say) are obviously on topic, but this I am less sure of.

Answer (score 9):

Ganesh has pointed out that they are explicitly prohibited in the help center. We could certainly change that if the community wanted to.

I would be against such a change. We don't need any more reason to attract low quality posts. Allowing these discussions would attract people who are interested in pumping or shorting a specific stock. We don't need any of that here.

Comment: It would also attract out-and-out spam. And even good questions/answers would become out of date quickly - similar to the problems with "product and service recommendations".

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam I wonder if we would attract more chat users if we added a room specifically for asking about products and services.

Comment: Can't hurt to try

Comment: @NathanL - the main chat room gets frozen for lack of activity every few weeks. I doubt a room dedicated to any one topic would garner activity. (That said, I echo Ganesh, no harm trying)

Answer (score 7):

No, they're off-topic - see https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic:

> ### What about other money and finance related questions?
>
> **Please note that the following subjects are considered off-topic here:**
>
> [...]
>
> Requests for specific investment buy/sell advice; e.g. "should I sell X?" or "should I buy Y?" or "will X continue to go up?"

Answer (score 2):

> Does TGNA's position in broadcasting and low PE make it a compelling value play?

This is a bad question for the site because it changes constantly.  So the right answer today may be wrong tomorrow.  Maybe on chat instead, although a forum for that purpose might be better.

That said, I don't think that all product questions should be off-topic.  For example, someone who bought 100 shares of Mylan in 2000 might ask why they now have 225 shares (answer:  two splits).  Because that's a historical question, the answer will stay the same in the future.  And of course, it's more objectively based.

Explaining how one found the answer could also help people with similar questions find their own answers in the future.

Comment: IMHO, questions of historical fact of that nature don't necessarily fall under the off-topic description of *"Requests for specific investment buy/sell advice; e.g. [...]"*. One more example: Taxation treatment of, say, spin-off or acquired shares is a matter beyond straight buy/sell advice that, as you point out, could also help others looking for the same information, if such is not otherwise simple to find or understand. It is prognostication we wish to avoid.